# Outlook Renamed the "Sent" Folder to the Name of a Contact

Tags: exchange, outlook-2007

I have a client who uses Outlook to sync to an Exchange server. His "Sent" folder was renamed to the name of one of his contacts. I know, it is really weird. Unfortunately, Outlook does not give you the ability to rename the Sent folder. Does anyone have a clue as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, someone had a great response at SuperUser:

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" /resetfoldernames

Comment: `/resetfoldernames` does not work in Office/Outlook365